# How can I replace Ubuntu branding with my own?

Tags: custom-distributions, logo, branding

How can I replace the Ubuntu branding with my own?

What files need to be replaced?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but `apt-cache search branding` *should* tell you what to change to make a rebranded respin

Comment: you have to specify all locations

Comment: check this [link][1]  and [this website][2]


  [1]: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-boot-splash-screen-logo-linux/
  [2]: http://modifyubuntu.com/

Comment: You want to modify the logo at Unity launcher only or everywhere?

Comment: I need to change everywhere

Comment: @user61928: Which version of Ubuntu are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

If you just wanna change the look of Ubuntu then check [Super Boot Manager](http://www.unixmen.com/super-boot-manager-great-tool-to-manage-burg-grub2-and-plymouth-in-ubuntu/)

If want to customize your distribution use [relinux](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux)

1. get the latest version from [here](https://launchpad.net/relinux)
2. The archive file contains two folders and an installation guide; the two folders must be merged with the original `etc` and `usr` folders. Change into the directory you unpacked the two folders to, in my example it is the `/home/MYUSER/Downloads` folder:

   `cd /home/MYUSER/Downloads`
3. Copy the downloaded folders to the original ones:

   `sudo cp -R usr /`

   `sudo cp -R etc /`

   Relinux should now be properly installed. You can find further documentations in the `/usr/share/doc/relinux/README` file.
4. Install Software

   To create yourself a unique distributable Ubuntu DVD you need to install the software you want on it on your current system. Do this by opening `Synaptic Package Manager` and use the search bar to find the packages you want to install.  Click the checkbox right next to the package and select  `Mark for Installation`.

   Most packages will need to install more packages they're dependent on, you will need to `Mark` those too.

   After you have selected all the packages you want, click the `Apply` button.

   All software you have installed on your current system will later automatically be transferred to the iso-image of you DVD. Make sure that the content you want on your DVD does not exceed the size of **4GB**! Otherwise **Relinux** will not produce an **.iso** file out of the filesystem
5. Use **Relinux**

   **Relinux** uses a config file for every command which you better edit before you use the program for the first time. Leave the original config as backup and create a new one in a specified location (I'll do it in my personal folder):

   `cd /home/MYUSER

   cp /etc/relinux/relinux.conf ./relinux.conf`
6. Next direct **Relinux** to the new configuration file:

   `sed -i 's:EXCLUDES="\(.*\)":EXCLUDES="\1 '`readlink -f ./relinux.conf`'":g' ./relinux.conf`

   It is highly recommended to have a look at all the options in the config file and adjust them to your liking. If you do not exclude enough files to bring the squashed file system to a maximum of 4 GB, **Relinux** will not create an image out of it. Additionally there are other helpful options like the choice of a boot splash screen or the naming of the actual image.

   **Relinux**' actual control is only possible through the command line. It generally has the same options as **Remastersys** at the moment except for the lack of an explicit **backup** command, which however can be accomplished by not excluding the **home folder**:

   - `sudo relinux clean [configfile]` - Cleans the working directory of unimportant process stuff
   - `sudo relinux fullclean [configfile]` - Cleans the working directory completely, including the .iso image, the checksum and all other files
   - `sudo relinux squashfs [configfile]` - Creates the squashed file system to build the iso-image out of. This is the necessary step to take before actually creating an iso-image. This can also be used to retroactively add files to the file system before creating the images
   - `sudo relinux onlyiso [configfile]` - Creates the actual iso-image which can be used in a virtual machine or burned on a CD to boot your custom system from (before choosing this option a file system must have been created using **squashfs**)
   - `sudo relinux iso [configfile]` - Creates the squashed file system and the .iso image in one command

   Since you most likely want to use the image you create for burning it on a DVD you should pay attention to the summed size of software and files you add to it.

   Every file created with **Relinux** will be placed in its temporary directory, which by default is **/home/relinux**. That counts for filesystems as well as for images (e.g. **custom.iso** by default). Be sure you move your image to some other place since this temporary folder will be emptied on the use of **fullclean**.
7. Add Files to a Non-Backup Filesystem Without **home-folder**

   If you have a home folder that is to large to put it on a DVD but still have files that need to be on the image, there are two ways you can put them on it; one has to be dealt with before you create the file system and one that can also be done after it has been created.

   a. `/etc/Skel` Folder

   To add files to your non-backup image before you create the file system, just put them into the `/etc/Skel` folder to let the files appear in your home folder on the image afterwards. The `/etc/Skel` folder is responsible for populating the home folder on every installation and every adding of a new user.

   b. `Squashfs-tools`

   **Squashfs-tools** is package that allows you to build and uncompress but also to add files to squashed filesystems, which are also used to build the filesystem on **Remastersys** and **Relinux**. They can be used to append files to already created filesystems. Install them by entering the following into a terminal:

   sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools

   The **squashfs-tools** offer two commands to use, one to create filesystems or add files to existing and one to uncompress them. The first one is

   mksquashfs

   And its basic structure is the command followed by one or more source files or folders and the path to the squashed file (e.g. `mksquashfs /home/MYUSER/Desktop/bla /home/MYUSER/Desktop/ultimate.squashfs`).

   The last folder in the path of the source file will be the root of the squash filesystem unless you specify otherwise with an option, meaning it will not be directly displayed itself.

   The same command is also used to append files to existing squash filesystems, which is what we basically want.

   To do so, just pick the existing filesystem as the filesystem to create and the files to append in the input files' path.

   Unfortunately, it is not possible to merge the two filesystems, which is why we circumvent this problem by creating a folder called **extrafiles** (could be any name) in any folder and choose this upper folder as the one to add to the system (it will become the root folder and the folder inside, the one we want, will be displayed along the files in the filesystem's root folder).

   Add the files you want on your DVD to the **extrafiles** folder. Following would be a possible way to add files to the filesystem:

   `mksquashfs /home/MYUSER/Desktop/bla /home/remastersys/remastersys/ISOTMP/casper/filesystem.squashfs`

   In this example the folder bla is the one containing the **extrafiles** folder.

   See the man page for further switches and options.

   To uncompress a squash filesystem, use following command:

   `unsquashfs`

   The most common way to use this command should be combined with the `destination` switch. Make sure to choose an unexisting directory as destination since it will give you an error otherwise.

   `unsquashfs -d /home/MYUSER/Desktop/unexistingdirectory /home/remastersys/remastersys/ISOTMP/casper/filesystem.squashfs`

Comment: Where could i change logos?!

Comment: I need for the whole distro not for start-here only

Answer (score 2):

OK after searching through the Linux file system, i found few files (logos) which can be replaced to prevent copyright violation.

All the files resides in

```
    /usr/share/icons &
    /usr/share/pixmaps
```

File names to replace are (All files are in png or svg file format)

```
    start-here 
    distributor-logo
    ubuntu-logo
```

I will add more names if i will find in future. Also edit these files as per your requirements `/etc/issues.net` `/etc/lsb-release` `/etc/issue`

but then you have to edit `/usr/share/pyshared/aptsources/distro.py`

and assign values of original lsb-release file to variables like

```
   self.id="Ubuntu"
   self.codename="precise"
   self.description="Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS"
   self.release= 12.04
```