# How do I remove any Ubuntu brand and trademark from my Ubuntu install?

Tags: customization, custom-distributions

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and I would like to build a **completely de-branded** ISO of it. This means not just dropping the *Ubuntu* name from `/etc/lsb_release` but also deleting references in the text of the installation program, in the "about this computer" screen and so on.

I've already checked other questions but I do not consider them duplicate because:

- [How to de-brand Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32248/how-to-de-brand-ubuntu) is very old and it just turned into a bunch of "try this tool" suggestions
- [How can I replace Ubuntu branding with my own?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194062/how-can-i-replace-ubuntu-branding-with-my-own) is also old and suggests a tool called `relinux` that hasn't seen updates in years
- [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) does mention APT packages (and I know how this works) but not trademarks

Therefore my questions are:

- Starting from a stock Ubuntu 17.10 (or an official derivative), how can I remove references to **the Ubuntu trademark and logo?**
- What exact packages do I need to uninstall?
- Are there images I need to replace? Are there files I need to edit other than `/etc/lsb_release`?

Please note that I am not interested in removing other names such as Firefox. I am only interested *in the name of the distro.*

Comment: You might have to remove Firefox as well (cf Iceweasel), and possibly any number of other software that have trademarks outside of the Ubuntu ones.

Comment: I think that to debrand the ISO would require you to rebuild a Linux environment starting from just the kernel and then manually adding in things you verify aren't 'branded' ('branding' is also extremely broad, so you have to define the *scope* of what you call 'branding').  *Everything* has 'brand names', even some basic things as the compilers (`GNU C++ Compiler` aka `g++/gcc` even is 'branded' as "GNU").  And at that point it's not 'debranding' but 'building from scratch', and I don't think you can do that very easily.

Comment: @muru thank you. My question is specifically about the Ubuntu brand. Firefox and other tools allow redistribution especially when they are not modified. My aim is to create a derivative live CD which needs a name not containing "Ubuntu".

Comment: @ThomasWard sorry for the double comment, but only one mention is allowed. As I said, my question is only about the Ubuntu logo and trademark. Is it unclear? Should I edit the wording? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto You may want to add that clarification, if there's more inquiries.  But removing 'ubuntu' from everything will require you to basically rebuild the entire repository with new version strings.  Do `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0` on a 16.04 system, you'll see the 'version' string is 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10.  So unless you rebuild all the packages with 'ubuntu' in the version string as well, you can't *easily* debrand everything.  Removing every trace of 'ubuntu' in the system is nontrivial, and will require a *ton* of work.  Unless you mean only in the GUI / default installed files?

Comment: @ThomasWard I don't think OP wants to remove those "ubuntu" names from packages, because even Linux Mint which is a standalone distro doesn't have those "ubuntu" names removed. Sorry for intervening, I'm just so interested in this question all of a sudden, so thought I could help.

Comment: @ThomasWard as Shayan pointed out, leaving package names are fine for me. Just assume I want to replace the strings in the GUI, the boot screen and lsb-release. Something similar to what Linux Mint must have done initially to start the derivative.

Comment: I don't believe anyone has ever documented every single location in which contains the "Ubuntu" string. You'd be doing this alone. Be good to document it for the next person who asks this :)

Comment: @popey, if the answer were to be found with a simple web search I would not have bothered asking. :)

Comment: I'm not saying you didn't search. I'm saying the thing you're after has been asked before, and I know that we (Canonical) have never written this up.

Comment: You have to ask permission: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2015-November/002179.html

Comment: @oldfred, quite the contrary. One has to ask permission when working on a derivative that *does* use the Ubuntu trademark. I am asking how to remove any possibly infringing display of said trademark.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Are you wanting a desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, LXDE) or any extra packages (Firefox, Epiphany, etc)?

Comment: Also many things would need recompiling.

Comment: @ubashu, most apps do not show the word Ubuntu anyway. The most important parts are the help center, the GUI and Ubiquity during installation.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yep, those things (help center, GUI, Ubiquity) would most likely need recompiling.

Comment: @ubashu I am not sure. The help center surely loads localized HTML/XML data from disk, and some other apps may use .po files I guess.

Comment: Sorry for interfering, but the question was interesting enough to make me wonder... Anyway, I did some Google searches and found this: https://gitlab.com/remastersys/LinuxRespin I am not sure if this is of any help in this case, but I felt that I should better mention it anyway... Do take in consideration the fact that I am not an advanced user...

Comment: @CristianaNicolae thank you for your comment. I think that tool doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04, but maybe they are working on it. I have developed my own solution to build a custom ISO, now I just need to figure out the places where the brand is located. :D I hope to be able to post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear whether you intend to distribute the unbranded distro, so apologies if this isn't your intention.

A new distribution with the branding removed would also need to recompile *all* the binaries from the source code.

https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

If you are going to use internally then it's just a job to locate all the text/image references but that isn't simple. All programs handle their text resources in various individual ways, so you aren't going to find it easy to identify all the branding to remove it.

Best to compile a list of everything that you consider 'brand', identify the underlying program delivering it and then you'll just need to start going through the code to find where it gets it from.

good luck

Comment: Please re-read the page you linked to: “For the avoidance of doubt, where any other licence grants rights, this policy does not modify or reduce those rights under those licences.” In particular, redistribution in source and/or binary form is permitted by the GPL, MIT and Apache licenses. If there are some packages that do really need to be compiled, it would be useful to know which ones. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto : As I said, depends whether the OP is redistributing or not. Please see section 3 of the link I posted, which reads: Any redistribution of modified versions of Ubuntu must be approved, certified or provided by Canonical if you are going to associate it with the Trademarks. Otherwise you must remove and replace the Trademarks and will need to **recompile the source code** to create your own binaries.

Comment: Canonical can write what they want... As long as the trademarks are removed, any GPL / MIT / Apache software can be redistributed _without_ recompiling. If there are proprietary components that are not covered under a OSS license, it would be **really really useful** to know which ones. So we can focus on recompiling those ones only.