# How do I remove all Ubuntu branding and logos for a new distribution?

Tags: custom-distributions

I am currently working on a modified version of Ubuntu, which I am considering distributing online. According to the Ubuntu Intellectual Property Rights Policy (https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy) I need to remove all mention of Ubuntu in the finished software and "recompile the source code to create my own binaries." How would I go about this, and what does the section in quotes mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Dupe, when/if it gets answered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017305/how-do-i-remove-any-ubuntu-brand-and-trademark-from-my-ubuntu-install