# How can I change the image(Logo of ubuntu inside Laptop image) which we get during Installation while selecting language?

Tags: 22.04, custom-installer, initrd

I am creating a customize image of ubuntu 20.04.3 using Cubic. I want to change the ubuntu logo present inside the laptop image.I am using Ubiquity installation framework.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE5gn.png)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1017305/1004020

Comment: Ubuntu is available with different installers and you've not said which you're actually wanting to use?  Why not just tell us instead of making us guess from a picture??  20.04.3 ISOs existed using `subiquity`, `ubiquity` (& `calamares` for flavor(s) thus likely doesn't relate here)

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubiquity installation framework.